# How to compare a torch::tensor shape against some other shapes?

Tags: c++, torch, libtorch

I'm trying to compare a `torch::Tensor`'s `sizes` agains something else, but it seems I'm doing it wrong.

I tried:

```cpp
    auto t = torch::ones({ 3,3 }).sizes();
    std::cout << c10::IntArrayRef{ 3,3 } << std::endl;
    std::cout << (t.equals(c10::IntArrayRef{ 3,3 })) << std::endl;
```

which always returns false.

I also tried:

```cpp
t == c10::IntArrayRef{ 3,3 };
```

which also returns false. Since IntArratRef doesn't own a storage itself, I tried:

```cpp
c10::IntArrayRef x(std::vector<int>{ 3, 3 });
```

but it fails, saying:

```
Error   C2664   'c10::ArrayRef<int64_t>::ArrayRef(c10::ArrayRef<int64_t> &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<T,std::allocator<int>>' to 'const T &'
```

I'm currently comparing each dimension individually which is far from desirable not to mention cumbersome. What's wrong here?

### Update:

This error shouldnt happen, if it happens for you heres an issue that was made in pytorch github repository at [issue-43611](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/43611).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. The first and second code samples output `true` on my machine. Can you double-check that you have correctly copy-pasted your code here ? If yes, can you add your pytorch version ?

Comment: By the way, the code with the vector just need two corrections : first make it  `long` (not `int`), then create your vector out of the IntArrayRef constructor, otherwise the vector is destroyed right after, thus freeing its memory

Comment: I'm using Pytorch1.6. and its weird it doesnt work for me! also `std::vector<long> vec{ 3, 3 };
    c10::IntArrayRef x( vec );` and neighther `std::vector<long> vec{ 3, 3 };
    c10::IntArrayRef x( {vec} );` work for me either. it gives me compilation error!

Comment: Well, if you are absolutely positive that this is the code you use without any copy-paste error, I suggest you try and ask on pytorch forums or raise an issue on github. I have tried with version 1.2.0 and 1.4.0 (do not have 1.6 sorry) and your code definitely works for me (including your 2 tries with vector<long>)

Comment: yeah, its the exact same code. Thanks a lot really appreciate your kind help

Comment: Found the cause, this happens to me when I'm in debug mode only. in release it works fine! filled an issue in pytorch repo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <ATen/ATen.h> // minimal tensor header for faster compilation

using namespace std;

int main() {

    at::IntArrayRef size1 = { 4, 5 };       // declare size (4 rows x 5 cols)
    at::IntArrayRef size2 = { 4, 6 };       // declare size (4 rows x 6 cols)

    at::Tensor t1 = at::zeros(size1);       // allocate a tensor of zeros

    // compare tensor sizes
    cout << (t1.sizes() == size1) << endl   // true
        << (t1.sizes() == size2) << endl;   // false

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```